# Looking in a Column for value and returning the row

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new to programming so sorry if this is a basic question. What I would like to do is look in the column header Secondary, and return all the rows that have it as a value. The plan will then be to export that output to excel.

1. `import pandas as pd`
2. `import numpy as np`
3. `os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Desktop')`
4. `df=pd.read_excel('test2.xlsx',sheet_name="Sheet1",header=4)`
5. `list(df.columns.values)`

Out[9]:
`['Trade Date', 'Trade time', 'Settlement', 'Primary', 'Secondary']`

Therefore if the value in the Primary column is equal to "Germany" to then return all the rows that contain it.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to SO. Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50308893/edit) to show us your desired output and what, if anything, you have tried so far? Specifically, what do you mean by `return all the rows that have it as a value`?

Comment: I believe by "it" he meant `Italy`. This is basic data selection, take a look at the docs https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html . You basically want `df[df.Secondary == "Italy"]`

Comment: thank you RafaelC that is what I was after, cant believe it was that simple

Comment: Please, remove salutations. [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can obtain all rows with a specific value as follows:

```
df.loc[df['column_name'] == specific_value]
```